# Python Merging Unequal Dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**Context**

I am trying to merge 2 csv files. df has 20k rows, df2 has 300k rows.

**Problem**

What I want is 20k row final dataframe, nothing else. But if I use merge I get 300k or 320k results. How can I do it?

I have dataframes like below

df

```
Userid  Transaction  Date
1919197    ab1       2018
797474     cb2       2017
```

df2

```
Userid    Country   Device
1919197    AU       IOS
797474     GB       Android
```

I would like to join them like this:

df3

```
Userid   Transaction  Date   Device
1919197    ab1        2018    IOS
```

UserID's are same on both dataframes and unique. Df and Df2 has duplicate rows for same UserId as one user can have many transactions or have many Devices and we don't want to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Just ude how:
`pd.merge(df, df2, how='left’)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply but unfortunately I don't get the final result I need, final Df is not 20k.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2[['Userid','Device',]], on = 'Userid', how = 'left')
```